# How do I wait for a file to be created inside a folder and once it creates it, the code proceeds to the next step?

Tags: python

So I wanted to create a script with Python that automatically moves files from a big database to a local folder. I simply recreated a:
1 drag & drop function with x and y coordinates where the mouse goes
2 click
3 drag to the folder
4 goes back on the database
5 press "Down arrow"
6 starts again.
The problem is that these files have different sizes so I wanted to add a point after "3." that waits for a single file to be fully created inside the folder, then proceeds with the rest of the code. Once it finishes it starts again but the condition is already found so it completely skips it and pass to the next step. How do I solve this? It's my first code ever so I really have no idea of what to do.

This is the current code

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui

toggle = False
path = 'insert path here'

def on_toggle():
    global toggle
    toggle = not toggle
    print("Script " + ("attivato" if toggle else "disattivato"))

def run_script():
    global toggle
    while toggle:
        # 1. First mouse position
        pyautogui.moveTo(1352, 675, duration=0.15)

        # 2. click
        pyautogui.click()

        # 3. move mouse position
        pyautogui.moveTo(1374, 948, duration=0.15)

        # 4. drag and drop
        pyautogui.mouseDown()
        pyautogui.moveTo(567, 673, duration=0.15)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()

        # wait for new file to be created inside the folder
        while not any(filename.endswith('.wav') for filename in os.listdir(path)):
            pass

        # 5. move the mouse again
        pyautogui.moveTo(1249, 670, duration=0.15)
        
        # 6. click
        pyautogui.click()

        # 7. press down arrow
        keyboard.press_and_release('down')

    print("Script terminato")


# F8 starts and stops the script
keyboard.add_hotkey('f8', on_toggle)
print("Premi F8 per attivare/disattivare lo script")

# starts the script 3 seconds after I press F8
time.sleep(3)
print("Script avviato")
run_script()
```

I know the while function should work differently but I really have no idea how, please send help.

Comment: Look for one of the many Python wrappers for `inotify` (if this is Linux; you haven't specified the OS, and this is a place where the interfaces are OS-specific; if you're on Windows, the `win32file`-based section of http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html might be where you want to start)

Comment: ...also see https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/ as a library that wraps several of the OS-specific interfaces to provide a more portable option.

Comment: BTW, note also that you probably want to wait for a file to be _closed post-write_ instead of waiting for it to be _created_. If you wait for things to be _created_ you can try to read them when they're empty or only partially written, and that doesn't work out so well.